# Passing set of file Paths from the command line to on "npm run test"?

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm using Testcafe for uploading files to my application, I need to run the command "npm run test". Currently, I've hard coded the file path in my spec script.

What I want to achieve is to run the same spec in a loop over an n-times with n-different files. As of now the only way to achieve this for me is to write n-specs for n-files with different filenames, but I don't want to do this as all specs are the same.

```
fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://mywebsite.org`;

test
    .before( async t => {
     console.log("User Log Tests");
     })
    ('File_Upload', async t => {
    await t
    .click('.home-search-btn')
    .wait(5000)
    .click('.menu.icon.large-visibility>ul>li:last-
    child>ul>li>.checkbox')
    .setFilesToUpload('input[type="file"]', [
        'home/name/fileDirectory/file.json',
     ])
    .click('.icon.base-upload')
    });
```

I wanted to know if it's possible to automate so filenames can be read from some directory and substitute in my specs.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to perform the same actions for several filenames you can keep a list of them in a file and use it in a loop inside the fixture or inside the test. For example if you have an array of file paths in the `files.js` file you can use the following approach:

```
// files.js
export default files = ['file1.json', 'file2.json'];

// test.js
import files from './files.js';

fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://mywebsite.org`;

for(const file of files) {
    test
    .before( async t => {
        console.log("User Log Tests");
    })
    (`File_Upload - ${file}`, async t => {
        await t
            .click('.home-search-btn')
            .wait(5000)
            .click('.menu.icon.large-visibility>ul>li:last-child>ul>li>.checkbox')
            .setFilesToUpload('input[type="file"]', [file])
            .click('.icon.base-upload')
    });
}
```